# method of range of object _global failed - simple for each loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a simple for each loop that iterates through each cell in the column to check if it is an numeric value, and if it is, it copies the value from that cell and pastes it in the adjacent cell in the next column. I'm getting a `method of range of object _global failed` error on the `cell.Copy Destination:=Range(Range("C1").End(xlUp))` line

```
' 1) For each cell in column A:
' 2)  If cell is numeric:
' 3)      copy value and paste in column c
' 4)  End if
' 5)  Next cell

Sub copyId()
Dim row As Range, myCell As Range

Set row = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))

' 1) For each cell in column A:

For Each cell In row

' 2)  If cell is numeric:
' 3)      copy value and paste in column c
    If IsNumeric(cell) Then
        
        cell.Copy Destination:=Range(Range("B1").End(xlUp))
    
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This can only ever be B1...   `Range("B1").End(xlUp)`

Comment: `cell.Copy Destination:=cell.Offset(0, 2)` should work if you mean Col C not B as in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays is effective and fast.

```
Sub copyId()
    Dim row As Range, myCell As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, vResult() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Set row = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    vDB = row
    ' 1) For each cell in column A:
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vResult(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    
    For i = 1 To r
    'For Each cell In row
    
    ' 2)  If cell is numeric:
    ' 3)      copy value and paste in column c
        If IsNumeric(vDB(i, 1)) Then
        'If IsNumeric(cell) Then
            
            'cell.Copy Destination:=Range(Range("B1").End(xlUp))
            vResult(i, 1) = vDB(i, 1)
        
        End If
    'Next cell
    Next i
    Range("c1").Resize(r, 1) = vResult
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `Evaluate()` (in this case I'm assuming there's no existing content in ColC which you wouldn't want to get overwritten) :

```vba
With ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = .Parent.Evaluate(Replace("IF(ISNUMBER(<a>),<a>,"""")", _
                                                "<a>", .Address(False, False)))
End With
```